# Scala: Turn Array into DataFrame or RDD

Tags: arrays, scala, list, apache-spark

I am currently working on IntelliJ in Maven. 
Is there a way to turn an array into a dataframe or RDD with the first portion of the array as a header?

I'm fine with turning the array into a List, as long as it can be converted into a dataframe or RDD.

Example:

input

```
val input = Array("Name, Number", "John, 9070", "Sara, 8041")
```

output

```
+----+------+
|Name|Number|
+----+------+
|John| 9070 |
|Sara| 8041 |
+----+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val ss = SparkSession
  .builder
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("test")
  .getOrCreate()

val input = Array("Name, Number", "John, 9070", "Sara, 8041")

val header = input.head.split(", ")
val data = input.tail
val rdd = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val df = rdd.map(x => (x.split(",")(0),x.split(",")(1))).toDF(header: _*)
df.show(false)

+----+------+
|Name|Number|
+----+------+
|John| 9070 |
|Sara| 8041 |
+----+------+
```